# Django Restframework with nested json and custom key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Iam using Django with Restframework.
Iam trying to get a json output from serializers in a nested manner with key as one of the fields from model. I acheived the nested JSON but the json key for them is troubling me.

Here is my code and expected results out of it:

Models.py

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    tagId = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100, default=1)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.section

class TagItem(models.Model):
    section= models.ForeignKey(Tags, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1,related_name="items")
    select = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py

```
class TagItemModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TagItem
        fields = '__all__'


class TagModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = TagItemModelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tags
        fields = ['pk','section', 'items']
```

Expected output:

```
 {
    "crafts" : {                //craft is comming from Tag model's "section"
        "id": 1,
        "section": "crafts",
        "items": [
          {
            "id": "10",
            "select": false,
            "name": "Wood",   
            "category": "crafts"   
          },

        ]
      },
    "states" : {
        "id": 2,
        "section": "states",
        "items": [
          {
            "id": "20",
            "select": false,
            "name": "Andhra Pradesh",
            "category": "states" 
          }
        ]
      },
      "others" : {
      "id": 3,
      "section": "others",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "30",
          "select": false,
          "name": "Volunteer",
          "category": "others" 
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Current output:

```
[                                           //cant get the key of Tag model's "section"
    {
        "pk": "1",
        "section": "states",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "select": false,
                "name": "Assam",
                "section": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pk": "2",
        "section": "others",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 12,
                "select": false,
                "name": "Artisan",
                "section": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pk": "3",
        "section": "crafts",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "select": false,
                "name": "Metal",
                "section": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your case, you would like to have a custom representation I think?

You can adjust it with overriding `to_representation()`

I provide two approaches:

#### serializer -> the better way but not quite the output you prefer

##### view

```
class TagModelView(views.APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        qs = Tags.objects.all()
        serializer = TagModelSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

##### serializer

```
class TagItemModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = TagItem
        fields = ['id', 'select', 'name', 'category']

    def get_category(self, instance):
        return instance.section.section


class TagModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = TagItemModelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tags
        fields = ['pk', 'section', 'items']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        container = super().to_representation(instance)
        return {container.get('section'): container}
```

#### Making representation in your view -> output you would like to get

##### view

```
    def get(self, request):
        qs = Tags.objects.all()
        serializer = TagModelSerializer(qs, many=True)

        container = dict()
        for element in serializer.data:
            container.update(**element)

        return Response(data=container)
```

##### serializer

No change to my proposal obove.

##### update

I saw that your primary key of `Tags` is `tagId` and you are using `fields = ['pk', 'section', 'items']` but you would like to have `id` as a key-name.

Relabeling can help you.

```
class TagModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = TagItemModelSerializer(many=True)
    id = serializers.CharField(source='tagId')

    class Meta:
        model = Tags
        fields = ['id', 'section', 'items']
```

Comment: Hi @Klim, Sorry for the late reply. I tried the above solution, and it worked quite well! Thanks a lot!

Comment: But on a curious case, how does this ```return instance.section.section``` worked? I mean section comes twice, what kind of sorcery was that? And I cant find this get_category, is this part of DRF?

Comment: @Ankzious. 1. `instance` is one of many `TagItem`-objects because we wrote TagModelSerializer(qs, **many=True**) and `qs` is a `QuerySet` and the serializer iterates over it. `get_<custom_name>(...)` is a [method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) that can do anything what you would like to display.  At `instance.section.section`, `instance` is your current `TagItem`-object. `.section` is the fieldname of your `ForeignKey` in `TagItem`-model and the second `.section` is the fieldname of your `CharField` in `Tags`-model

Comment: @Ankzious If you use `get_<display_name>`, DRF takes `<display_name>` as a key and uses it for displaying what your method is returning. It is a ´read_only´-field and cannot be used for saving/updating.